# How to get content page from XUL?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

i cannot get current content page html. when i trying access from script in xul element. not current open url.

i use this code:

```js
alert(document.getElementById("html"));
```

it will alert **null** value, document return XUL object, not Html object. 
I want parsing current content page, but i dont know how to do it.

```js
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
               .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
               .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
               .rootTreeItem
               .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
               .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

    alert(mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href);
    alert(mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.document);
```

when i use this code, no alert shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var win = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
           .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
           .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

win.alert(win.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href);
```

If you run this code from the `window` context, you can just remove the first part and have:

```
alert(window.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use `content` before `document`, for example:

```
alert(content.document.getElementById("html"));
```

may be you want to `achieve` this:

```
alert(content.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML);
```